# Is there a way to get the file import dependencies for different files in a Python project?

Tags: python

I'm working with a Python project consisting of multiple files and nested directories. I want to get a dictionary consisting of all existing files and their references to other files (nesting not required), for example:

```
dependencies = {
    "file1.py": ["file2.py","file4.py"],
    "file2.py": ["file3.py","file4.py",
    "file3.py": ["file1.py"],
    "file4.py": []
}
```

Is there a module or an existing approach already out there to accomplish this?

My current plan is to write a program to read each line in every file and just track what comes after any `from` or `import` statement, but I'm not sure if that method's airtight.

Pseudocode:

```
dependencies = {}
for file in directory:
    for line in file:
        if line begins with "import" or "from":
            dependencies[file] += everything_after_from_import(line)
return dependencies
```

I looked at modules like `pipdeptree`, but those only seem to track pip dependencies, rather than imports from file-to-file. I also don't need to worry about performance or scalability, as this is for generating an offline report for my own reference.

Is my current approach the best, or are there better ways out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for exactly that myself so I wrote this tool that can dump all python file dependencies as a tree and tell what they are and if they are available(basic import static analysis):

```
https://github.com/bedbad/pyimports
```

Your thinking to use ast is right, however you don't need to read in or grep any token of source file - you can just ask ast for proper nodes:

To get dependencies of all files in the directory is simple repetition of that process in a loop, although it can be amended.

```
def get_imports(path):
imports = dict()
with open(path) as fh:
    root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)
    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            temp = imports
            for n in node.names:
                namelist = n.name.split('.')
                if len(namelist) > 1:
                    for st in namelist:
                        temp[st] = dict()
                        temp = temp[st]
                else:
                    temp[n.name] = dict()
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
            temp = imports
            namelist = node.module.split('.')
            for n in namelist:
                temp[n] = dict()
                temp = temp[n]
            for n in node.names:
                temp[n.name] = dict()
        else:
            continue
return imports
```